# Swift 5: How can i get data from NSSingleObjectArray?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm fetching data from a Google Translator API. I'm not sure how to access the description?

all my attempts have failed, help, please

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                var data = json as! [String: Any]
                data = data["data"] as! [String:Any]
                print(data!)
```

that I fetch in the console:

```
["translations": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002837350>(
{
    detectedSourceLanguage = en;
    translatedText = "\U0420\U0430\U0431\U043e\U0442\U0430";
}
)
]
```

cite my code, i'm just learning, if there is a way to parse this json without using structures, please show me. I think that the use of structures in this case is not justified, because the json response is small and i only need to get 2 parameters, am I right?

Comment: `let translations = data["data"] as? [[String; String]]; let firstTranslation = translations.first; let translated = first translation["translatedText"]` ?

Comment: I meant `let translations = data["translations"] as? [[String: String]]`.

Comment: This would be significantly easier with `JSONDecoder` and `Decodable`. Using structures is always justified unless you duplicate code. The difference in code readability is enormous.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code:

```
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        var data = json as! [String: Any]
        data = data["data"]! as! [String:Any]
        let translations = data["translations"] as? [[String: String]]
        let firstTranslation = translations?.first
        let translated = firstTranslation!["translatedText"]
        print(translated)
```